# Rails: why this weird error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to use jquery drag and drop uploader by following this example

https://github.com/jalagrange/bootstrap_uploader

My View:

```
   <%= form_for @object_new, :html => { :multipart => true, :id => "fileupload"  } do |f| %>
        <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
        <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
          <div class="span7">
            <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                    <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Add files...</span>
                  <%= f.file_field :path, :multiple => true %>
                </span>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
              <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
              <span>Start upload</span>
            </button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
              <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
              <span>Cancel upload</span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
              <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
              <span>Delete</span>
            </button>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
          </div>
          <div class="span5">
            <!-- The global progress bar -->
            <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active fade">
              <div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- The loading indicator is shown during image processing -->
        <div class="fileupload-loading"></div>
        <br>
        <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
        <table class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery"></tbody>
        </table>
    <% end %>
```

Controller:

```
 def upload
       @object_new= Property::File.new

  end
```

Model:

```
class Property::File < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date, :description, :location, :name, :time ,:path
end
```

Schema:

```
  create_table "property_files", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.string   "date"
    t.datetime "time"
    t.string   "location"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
    t.string   "path"
  end
```

routes.rb

```
  root :to => "property#home"  
  get "property/home"
  get "property/upload"
```

When I run my view I got this error:

```
NoMethodError in Property#upload

Showing C:/myproject/app/views/property/upload.html.erb where line #71 raised:

undefined method `property_files_path' for #<#<Class:0x563d3a8>:0x563b5a8>
Extracted source (around line #71):

68:     </div><!--/span-->
69:     <div class="span9">
70: 
71:     <%= form_for @object_new, :html => { :multipart => true, :id => "fileupload"  } do |f| %>
72:         <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
73:         <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
74:           <div class="span7">
Rails.root: C:/myproject
```

I don't understand where `property_files_path` is being used in view.

Thanks for any help

Comment: `property_files_path` is the route that the `form_for` tag generates as the default action for the form. The error clearly points out what line the error comes from.

Comment: How does your routes.rb look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's being called by the form generator.  For this to work you probably want to add:

```
resources :property_files
```

... to your routes.

If you do not want the form to default to resourceful routes, you can specify your own path for the upload action by passing the `url` option to `form_for`, for example:

```
<% form_for @object_new, {:url => "/property_files/upload", ... } %>
```